# Compute accuracy of TIMIT data set on an RNN model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

So I am trying to figure out how to compute the accuracy of an RNN model.

I have a batch size of 192, and every frame (TIMIT frame) is of the size of 490*129.
currently, I compute my accuracy as follows:

```
    for batch_x, batch_y, len_batch in val_loader:
    batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)
    logits = model(batch_x)
    loss_val = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)

    preds1 = logits.argmax(dim=-1)
    temp1 = batch_y.argmax(dim=-1)
    acc1 = preds1.squeeze().eq(temp1).sum().item()
    acc_rate1 = 100 * acc1 / (192 * 490)
```

But the accuracy that I receive seems wrong.

My train:

```
model.train()
print('number of epochs: {}'.format(args.epochs))

best_test = 1e7
best_validation = 1e7

losses_diagonal = []

for ep in range(1, 2):
    init_time = datetime.now()
    processed = 0
    step = 1

   
    for batch_idx, (batch_x, batch_y, len_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)

        opt.zero_grad()

        logits = model(batch_x)
        loss = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)
        loss.backward()

        if args.clip > 0:
            nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), args.clip)

        opt.step()

        processed += len(batch_x)
        step += 1
        losses_diagonal.append(loss)
        print("   batch_idx {}\tLoss: {:.2f} ".format(batch_idx, loss))

    print("Epoch {}, LR {:.5f} \tLoss: {:.2f} ".format(ep, opt.param_groups[0]['lr'], loss))
```

My test:

```
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():

    for batch_x, batch_y, len_batch in test_loader:
        batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)
        logits = model(batch_x)
        loss_test = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)

    for batch_x, batch_y, len_batch in val_loader:
        batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)

        logits = model(batch_x)
        loss_val = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)

    for batch_x, batch_y, len_batch in val_loader:
        batch_x, batch_y, len_batch = batch_x.to(device), batch_y.to(device), len_batch.to(device)
        logits = model(batch_x)
        loss_val = model.loss(logits, batch_y, len_batch)

        preds1 = logits.argmax(dim=-1)
        temp1 = batch_y.argmax(dim=-1)
        
        acc1 = preds1.squeeze().eq(temp1).sum().item()
        acc_rate1 = 100 * acc1 / (192 * 490)
        acc_rate1
        print('acc = {}, acc_rate = {}'.format(acc1,acc_rate1))

    if loss_val < best_validation:
        best_validation = loss_val.item()
        best_test = loss_test.item()

print()
print("Val:  Loss: {:.2f}\tBest: {:.2f}".format(loss_val, best_validation))
print("Test: Loss: {:.2f}\tBest: {:.2f}".format(loss_test, best_test))
print()

model.train()
```

I would like to get some help with computing the accuracy of my RNN model, and I am willing to publish some more of my code if it will be required.

Comment: You should certainly show more—the expectation on Stack Overflow is a [mre]. Shapes of variables would additionally be helpful.

Comment: Sure I will add some more code now

Comment: The most helpful thing, really, would be data. Show us preds1 and temp1 and tell us why you doubt the accuracy they’re giving you.